# Square inside a triangle problem [see desc.]

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, substitution, quartics

I Have a problem solving this problem only using high school math(Geometry)
without using digital help (computer). The solution should be $\cfrac{11\sqrt{77}}{2}$.

How can I get this solution by hand?
I get only a fourthgrade equation that I can not solve:
$(x+1)^2(x^2+1)= 100x^2$ using similar triangles. 
There most be an easier way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$$\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{10},$$ which indeed gives
$$100x^2=(x+1)^2(x^2+1).$$

Now, let $x+\frac{1}{x}=t$.

Thus, $$100=(t+2)t$$ or
$$(t+1)^2=101,$$ which gives $$t=\sqrt{101}-1$$ and $$x+\frac{1}{x}=\sqrt{101}-1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. But how do you choose the substitution t ?
And can you show me how you get  100 = (t+2)t by substituting, your calculations ?

Comment: I divided both sides by $x^2$ and used $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$.

Comment: Can you explain how you thought when you chose your substituion? Or If you know somewhere I can find videoes or anyting explaining this?

Comment: I just solved some number of problems during my life. I just see this substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Call the upper part of the vertical leg $y$. Then
$$(1+x)^2+(1+y)^2=100$$
and ${y\over1}={1\over x}$,
hence $xy=1$. Letting $x+y=:s$ we therefore have
$$2+2s+(s^2-2xy)=100\ ,$$
or $(s+1)^2=101$. This gives $s=\sqrt{101}-1$, so that by Vieta's theorem $x$ and $y$ are the solutions of the quadratic
$$z^2-(\sqrt{101}-1)z+1=0\ .$$